# How to merge dicts in list with different keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like `[{"username":"example"},{"password":"example2"},{"username":"example3"},{"password":"example4"}]`

So I want to merge objects with different keys.
It should looks like `[{"username":"example","password":"example2"},{"username":"example3","password":"example4"}]`

And actually I will not know keys always. This array creates dynamically.
So code should working any time. Ex: when there are four different key or three or six.

How can I achive this challenge ?

Thanks and best regards..

Comment: Is the order always correct?

Comment: Whats the expected output for [{"k1":"v1"},{"k2":"v2"},{"k2":"v3"},{"k2":"v3"}]

Comment: @DeepSpace yes always correct order

Comment: @SamarthS never it will be like that. if there are 2 key one. so there are 2 key two or key three

Comment: Are you just wanting to merge dicts that are adjacent in a list?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter just I want to merge dicts has different keys in one dict.

Comment: What's the expected output for [{"k1":"v1"},{"k1":"v2"},{"k2":"v4"},{"k2":"v3"}]

Comment: @SamarthS order always will be like [<dict has keyone>, <dict has keytwo>, <dict has keyone>, <dict has keytwo>] or if there are three key [<dict has keyone>, <dict has keytwo>,<dict has keythree>,<dict has keyone>, <dict has keytwo>,<dict has keythree>]

Comment: @Rasitaydin Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this will **always** output the correct output (you didn't provide many use cases) but I'm sure this will set you on the correct track:

```
li = [{"username":"example"},{"password":"example2"},
      {"username":"example3"},{"password":"example4"}]

dict_list = []

for d in li:
    if not dict_list:
        dict_list.append(d)
    else:
        for d_ in dict_list:
            if list(d.keys())[0] not in d_:
                d_.update(d)
            else:
                dict_list.append(d)
            break
```

`dict_list` is then

```
[{'username': 'example', 'password': 'example2'},
 {'username': 'example3'}, {'password': 'example4'}]
```

Even works if the order is not perfect,

```
li = [{"username":"example"}, {"username":"example3"}, 
      {"password":"example2"}, {"password":"example4"}]
```

Will provide the same output

Comment: Thank you very much friend :) Working very well even there are three or four different key.